# Does logback support log4j appenders?

Tags: logging, log4j, logback

Can custom appenders created for log4j (extending AppenderSkeleton) be used with new **logback** framework? I know that **logback** comes with its own set of appenders similar to log4j, but is this possible to re-use existing ones? How?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following document describes how to "[migrate] custom log4j components such as appenders or layouts to logback-classic":

http://logback.qos.ch/manual/migrationFromLog4j.html

Answer (score 6):

It should be easy to port a log4j appender  to logback. There is even a [document describing](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/migrationFromLog4j.html) the process. However, if you run into problems (which you should not), don't hesitate to ask for help on the logback-dev mailing list.

Answer (score 2):

No, logback appenders need to implement logback's [Appender](http://logback.qos.ch/xref/ch/qos/logback/core/Appender.html) interface.
Should be feasible to write a wrapper appender if you wanted to use an existing log4j appender.