# Using Hibernate Profiler with Logback

Tags: hibernate, log4j, profiler, logback

When using Hibernate Profiler with an application logging with Logback instead of Log4J, we must port the Hibernate Profiler Log4J appender to a Logback appender.
This is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974817/does-logback-support-log4j-appenders) for example.

Does someone already have developed this appender?

Comment: I'm in the exact same situation and finding your unanswered question doesn't sound good. Have you, by any chance, found a solution to your problem?

Comment: Unfortunately I have not found the solution...